# Nested If statement not selecting appropriate cell value

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have 3 combo boxes on a form.  The first is populated when the form loads, the second is populated when the user picks a value from the first combo box, and the third is populated when the user picks a value from the second.

When the third combo box is changed, I am using a nested If statement to determine what row this combination lies in (so I can populate textboxes on the form). However, the first If Statement is failing to trigger (i.e. return a 'true' value). There is an acceptable value in the cell, so it should progress to the next If statement, but it just jumps to the end of my While statement.

```
Private Sub cmb_State_Change()
    Dim Project, licence, state As String
    Dim selectedrow As Integer

    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim i, j As Integer

    selededrow = 0
    Project = cmb_Project.Value
    licence = cmb_Licence.Value
    state = cmb_State.Value

    i = 1
    j = 3
    While selectedrow = 0
        If Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(i, j) = Project Then
            i = i + 6
            If Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(i, j) = licence Then
                i = i - 1
                If Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(i, j) = state Then
                    selectedrow = j
                End If
            End If
        Else
            j = j + 1
            i = i - 5
        End If
    Wend

End Sub
```

Can anybody see why it would be behaving like this?

Comment: You should place `Option Explicit` as the first line of every code module.  That will pick up your typo.  (But may not cause your problem - I need to look more.)

Comment: If cell `C1` doesn't equal the value of `Project`, your code seems to then want to look at cell `D-4` next.  I can't see how that goes to the `Wend` rather than crashing.  Do you have some `On Error` statements in your code that you haven't shown in the question?  P.S.  Did you intend to declare `Project` (and `licence`) as `String`?  You currently have them declared as `Variant`.

Comment: Can you paste an image of the data contained in Worksheets("Entitlements") into the question please?  I'm having a lot of trouble visualising what you are doing with your row counter and why.

Comment: You have maths issue here, consider the first time in the loop, if Project isn't found, you `i = i - 5` which equals -4! So you should get error on next round - row starts from 1. You may be wanted to add/subtract `i` from the If lines instead. Also, why `selectedrow = j`? `j` is columns in your use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cells` takes its arguments as *rows then columns* so you need to reverse `i` and `j` in your code. When you do `Range("C4")` it is *columns then rows* i.e. column `C`, row `4` - but `Cells` is the other way around.

So, currently you have

```
If Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(i, j) = Project Then
i = i + 6
    If Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(i, j) = licence Then
        i = i - 1
        If Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(i, j) = state Then
                selectedrow = j
```

Which is making your second lookup 6 rows down - not 6 columns across.

Rewrite those as:

```
If Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(j, i) = Project Then
i = i + 6
    If Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(j, i) = licence Then
        i = i - 1
        If Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(j, i) = state Then
                selectedrow = j
```

### Another option

You can just rewrite the code block as this:

```
r = 3
While selectedrow = 0
    If Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(r, 1) = Project And _
        Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(r, 7) = licence And _
        Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(r, 6) = State Then

        selectedrow = r
    Else
        r = r + 1
    End If
Wend
```

### An even better option

Using the `While..Wend` loop means the code will run to the last row (over million rows) in the sheet if there is no match. You can use a standard bit of code to find the last row in your data:

```
Set ws = Worksheets("Entitlements")
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Then use a `For..Next` loop over that range. For example:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmb_State_Change()
    Dim Project As String, licence As String, state As String
    Dim selectedrow As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    selectedrow = 0
    Project = "hello" 'cmb_Project.Value
    licence = "world" 'cmb_Licence.Value
    state = "stuff" 'cmb_State.Value

    Set ws = Worksheets("Entitlements")
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For r = 3 To LastRow
        If ws.Cells(r, 1) = Project And _
            ws.Cells(r, 7) = licence And _
            ws.Cells(r, 6) = state Then

            selectedrow = r
            Exit For
    Next r

End Sub
```

Note the use of Option Explicit to catch any typos in your code. In your original question you had `Dim selectedrow As Integer` and `selededrow = 0` which would have thrown a compile time error if you were using `Option Explicit'.

Comment: you are an absolute legend - thanks for both picking out my original problem, and improving my code!!